# Trigger function when start running Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, triggers, tomcat8

On Eclipse(Java), when I click Run Tomcat8 , I want to log the time to inform when did the server start to run. I don't know how to trigger this logging action since I have to access a page to call the log function in controller file. Is there anyway that I can write a log file whenever I start running Tomcat8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this without any Spring or Tomcat specificity and have a solution runnable on all kind of Java EE applications you can create a class implementing `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` and get a notification that the web application is ready to process request in the method `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)`.

This method will be called when the application is deployed on the server.

```
package com.your.package;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class YourServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Place here the code to run once the application is ready 
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Place here the code to run just before the application goes down
    }

}
```

This listener needs to be configured into your web.xml  as follows

```
</web-app ...>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.your.package.YourServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: This works! I tested your solution with debug and got inside the contextInitialized function. Thanks!